Globe deploy Dart frog project
While running globe deploy command, getting below error.
Globe API Error.
There was an issue calling the Globe API, please try again.
 Use verbose mode using the --verbose flag for more details.
Validation error: Root directory must be a valid directory path. at "rootDirectory"; Entrypoint must be a valid dart file. at "entrypoint"

If I run the build logs with --verbose,
globe build-logs --deployment="129a0782-db12-4402-97f7-0a99a6f591cb" --verbose
I am getting below error.
Verbose logging enabled.
API Request: GET /user/orgs
API Request: GET /orgs/e4dbd4d1-bf61-48bf-9447-7f6d0ac9109e/projects
Validated scope: saurabh-d/todo-api
API Request: GET /orgs/e4dbd4d1-bf61-48bf-9447-7f6d0ac9109e/projects/d6f5e128-207d-47bd-a1a8-6e2b566fcd34/deployments/129a0782-db12-4402-97f7-0a99a6f591cb
Globe API Error.
There was an issue calling the Globe API, please try again.
 Use verbose mode using the --verbose flag for more details.
If this issue persists please contact support and provide these logs.
---
"Status Code": 404

"Headers":
connection: keep-alive
date: Sat, 09 Nov 2024 12:17:41 GMT
transfer-encoding: chunked
content-encoding: gzip
vary: Accept-Encoding
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server-timing: cfL4;desc="?proto=TCP&rtt=87764&sent=5&recv=7&lost=0&retrans=0&sent_bytes=2790&recv_bytes=1113&delivery_rate=33245&cwnd=252&unsent_bytes=0&cid=d46a9738be87004f&ts=2485&x=0"
cf-ray: 8dfdbdab0dbc8eee-BOM
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v4?s=F2dtEYZVAQG98jMXojXa1GW9ThVcvBjGsws3dyIHZthRwxz1c9bhvHvDF8NpmwLr6tAFBwUFNdns%2BE3LbbiQ0CWnp9xR2ZSlCGDM0QSB0mGMNSWeXGcLE%2F6qQYk%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
content-type: application/json
server: cloudflare

"Body":
{"title":"Resource Not Found","message":"The requested resource was not found."}
Instance of 'ApiException'

I have tried to select both of the below files as Dart entry point, but getting the same error.

build/bin/server.dart
.dart_frog/server.dart

My lib/main.dart as below.
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dart_frog/dart_frog.dart';

Future<HttpServer> run(Handler handler, InternetAddress ip, int port) {
  // 1. Execute any custom code prior to starting the server...

  // 2. Use the provided `handler`, `ip`, and `port` to create a custom `HttpServer`.
  // Or use the Dart Frog serve method to do that for you.
  return serve(handler, ip, port);
}

How to resolve the error and deploy APIs?
